# Transfer contacts and SMS from Samsung SGH-X830 to iPhone?

Tags: iphone, sms, contacts

I need to transfer contacts and SMS history from a Samsung SGH-X830 to an iPhone 3G. Preferably, I would like to preserve date/time for SMS messages. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

#### Contacts

Move to SIM card, move SIM to iPhone, move from SIM.

#### SMS

?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the SMS history is stored on the carriers servers, not your phone. So if you stay with the same carrier, you might be able to migrate them when you get the new phone.

Comment: AFAIK this is not the case in my region.

Answer (score 0):

#### SMS

The iPhone SMS DB is sqlite3. If your iPhone is jailbroken, you can get and view the DB on the phone itself (install terminal) or on your desktop:

```
# get it local
scp iphone:/var/mobile/Library/SMS/sms.db ./
# dump to ASCII
sqlite3 sms.db .dump > sms.db.sql
# edit it
emacs sms.db.sql
# Re-db
cat sms.db.sql | sqlite3 sms2.db;
# Put it back on the iPhone
scp sms2.db  iphone:/var/mobile/Library/SMS/sms.db
```

I don't have an Android and cannot tell you how to get the SMS DB off of Android, but you ought to be able to do something similar. You'll need to reverse engineer the formats of the two, write a converter, and convert your Android SMS DB to your iPhone SMS DB.

Here are some instructions on how to migrate your SMS in the reverse direction: http://android.riteshsahu.com/tips/import-sms-iphone-android

Comment: I am looking for a (mostly) automated, more useful solution for someone with no knowledge of SQL databases. This might work, but it's manual, tedious, and error prone. Thanks for pointing out the possibility, though.

Comment: The solution can be automated and scripted, but it would required SQL knowledge. If you broke the steps down and posted each as a question on a *.stackexchange.com site I bet you could get it done for you...