# How do I transfer text messages from my old Blackberry to my new iPhone?

Tags: iphone, sms

I recently bought an iPhone after using the same BlackBerry for 4 years. I have 25,000+ texts on it, that I would like to get on my iPhone. Does anyone know how I could accomplish this?

Comment: Similar: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2003/transfer-contacts-and-sms-from-samsung-sgh-x830-to-iphone

Answer (score 1):

I little bit of research found this program called [MyBB - Berry Backup Reader (iTunes Link)](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mybb-berry-backup-reader-contacts/id478661896?mt=8) for the princely sum of $2

> See the data from your blackberry backup file on your iPhone or iPad!
>
> I wrote this app because after I moved from a blackberry to an iPhone I found that I was still carrying my old phone around with me to gain access to all the data that I had stored, memos, contacts, calendar info etc. Using MyBB I have quick & easy access to this info if I need to look something up and I can copy and paste anything important that needs transferring into an iPhone document or message.

Comment: This could work :o I was hoping for something that would put my BlackBerry's messages in with my iPhone's, but this could be a happy half way.

Answer (score 0):

BlackBerry to iPhone switchers can now transfer contacts, calendars, text messages, email messages, etc. more stably with the latest update for BerryMover, an iPhone app. The 1.2 update adds support for Mac users’ data and improves the support for SMS messages.

The need for this app seems huge. In a United Sample survey last year, over 66% of Verizon-based BlackBerry users said they would switch to an iPhone when it became available. Therefore, the numbers are staggering.

Comment: Can you please add a link to the product as well?